# How to execute the following line of code in C# without needing to hit enter in cmd prompt?

Tags: c#, exe, process.start

I'm not experienced in C#. I tried calling a .NetCore exe file from a .NetFramework project but to execute the lines after `Store_MailData(); //a method`
I have to hit enter in the cmd prompt to be able to continue.
Why is it not even reading the following code? Advise Please :(

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MailActivity
{
    public class Program
    {        
        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Store_MailData(); // a method

            Console.WriteLine("Predicting intent... ");
            ForeignFile.GetForeignExecutable("C:\\...Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\ConsoleDotNet.exe");
            Console.WriteLine("Prediction effected. ");
         }

         public static void Store_MailData()
        {             
            string connectString = @"Data Source="+ Environment.MachineName + ";Initial Catalog=Case_Study;Integrated Security=True";

            var mails = OutlookEmails.ReadMailItems();
            int i = 1;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectString);
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server... ");
            con.Open();

            foreach (var mail in mails)
            {                
                try
                {                   
                    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {                                                
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblMail(Category, Date, Sender, CC, Subject, Recipient, Attachment, Body, Status) VALUES (@Category, @Date, @Sender, @CC, @Subject, @Recipient, @Attachment, @Body, @Status)", con);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailDate.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailSender;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailCC;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailSubject;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipient", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailRecipient.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailAttachment.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mail.EmailBody;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd.Dispose();
                        //Console.WriteLine("This serie is completed");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Error.Message);
                }
                i += 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closing server connection... ");
            con.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Total mails info sent to database: "+ (i-1));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }    
}
```

As for the Store_MailData(), it works as suppose to. It reads unread mails, download attachment, save to a folder and sql.

the `ForeignFile.GetForeignExecutable` (a class in the project) is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MailActivity
{
    public class ForeignFile
    {
        public static void GetForeignExecutable(string methodFile)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Process myProcess = new Process())
                {
                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = methodFile;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of `Store_MailData` is causing the program to halt until you hit enter. Remove the:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

and you'll be fine!